# Can I use a newer System.* assembly without .net standard?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

We have upgraded one of our Web projects to ASP.NET Core 2.0, and are now getting errors in other projects because of mismatched assembly version.  I am trying to upgrade all our conflicting assemblies to the highest version.

For example, the previous version of *System.Collections.Immutable* nuget package was 1.3.1, but the one that the ASP.NET Core 2 project references is in version 1.4.0.  So I try to change this in the .csproj files where *System.Collections.Immutable* is referenced:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Immutable" Version="1.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, this causes a compilation error:

> The version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk used by this project is insufficient to support references to libraries targeting .NET Standard 1.5 or higher.  Please install version 2.0 or higher of the .NET Core SDK.

First of all, I do have .NET Core 2.0 SDK installed. Googling around there was some suggestions that I add a **<DependsOnNETStandard>** property to the csproj file and reference NETStandard.Library.  However, I can't do that because our code makes full use of the .NET Framework, including stuff not in **netstandard**.

How can I get this to work?

FYI, we are on Visual Studio 15.3.3 and .NET 4.6.2.

Comment: You need to target `netstandard2.0` in your shared library, I think. This is still confusing.

Comment: I am using .NET Framework-only code in the library.  I tried to get it to work, but I couldn't.

Comment: Aluan, Visual Studio version 15.3.3 is Visual Studio 2017.  I am not targetting netcoreapp2.0; I am targetting the .NET framework 4.6.2.  I just need to reference my application's DLLs in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 project, and currently they are referencing different versions of System.Collections.Immutable, System.Diagnostics.Diagnosticsource, and System.Numerics.Vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Adding DependsOnNETStandard to the csproj file and a reference to NETStandard.Library doesn't break compatibility with full framework. I'm currently working on a project that does exactly this - ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1, referencing both .NET Standard and .NET Framework class libraries and dozens of OOB .NET Standard packages.